# Changing the AirDrop icon

Tags: macos, ios, airdrop

I'm using AirDrop to transfer files from my Mac to my iPad. The iPad appears in AirDrop as a picture of a tennis ball with my name underneath it.

A tennis ball is a very random thing to associate with me. It doesn't fit my personality at all, so I would like to change it. I don't particularly want to upload a picture, I just want to select a different one of the default images that Apple devices use for users. How can I do that?

I tried changing my picture in the "Apple ID" preferences both on the Mac and on the iPad. (There was no picture there before.) I also tried just changing my picture in the "Users & Groups" preferences on the Mac. Neither of these changed it, it's still a tennis ball.

Comment: On OSX a tennis ball is one of the standard "user" login images - and on OSX when you create a user it randomly chooses one.  My phone shows the same as on OSX - but I have logged into iCloud for them both at some stage - so that maybe is "sync'd".  So maybe you can change on the mac and while logged in (as the same user) it'll update the iPAD?? [or maybe I randomly got the same one on both devices ??]

Comment: Go to Users & Groups Preferences, click edit on your current icon, choose another one.

Comment: @MrR now I come to think of it, I think this computer gave me a tennis ball at first, and I later changed it. I just tried changing it on the computer again, but no luck - it still shows my iPad as a tennis ball in AirDrop

Comment: @lhf I think you might be thinking of changing the user icon on a Mac - there's no "Users & Groups" preferences on an iPad as far as I can tell. I did try changing it on the Mac just in case (see previous comment) but that didn't affect what AirDrop displays for the iPad.

Comment: On the iPad, Settings / Apple ID, click on icon. Also check your entry in Contacts.

Comment: @lhf changing my Apple ID photo doesn't change the tennis ball in AirDrop. I've tried changing it from both the computer and from the iPad. There's no photo associated with my entry in Contacts as far as I can tell, and I don't want to add one unless that will 100% definitely remove the tennis ball. (I don't think it will.)

Comment: @N.Virgo, I'm facing the same issue! When Airdropping from my iPhone to my Macbook, it shows the tennis ball icon